# Get currently executing javascript line in react native javascript engine for debugging

Tags: react-native

I am currently working on a react native app that seems to infinitely loop somewhere in its javascript when run on android. Unfortunately, it only does this in when running the javascript in the JavaScriptCore interpreter (the on-device javascript engine), if I debug it in the browser it works fine.

Because of that, I am looking for a way to get JavaScriptCore to divulge what code it is running from some sort of debugger. I have tried using the android studio debugger for this, but it only shows a native runner when javascript code is run, which doesn't show any information on what exactly it is running. How can I get that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have build a working solution for this using a babel plugin. Should anyone need it, adding the plugin below automatically adds logging to all function entries and exits. This should be enough information in most cases to work out what code is running at the time of a freeze.

```
module.exports = function({ types: t }) {
    return {
        visitor: {
            Function(path, state) {
                if (state.file.opts.filename.endsWith('/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/polyfills/console.js')) return;
                if (!t.isStatement(path.node.body)) return;
                if (typeof(path.node.loc) === 'undefined') return;
                path.get('body').unshiftContainer('body', 
                    t.expressionStatement(
                        t.callExpression(
                            t.memberExpression(
                                t.identifier('console'),
                                t.identifier('log')
                            ), [
                                t.stringLiteral("JSTracer ENTER:"),
                                t.stringLiteral(state.file.opts.filename),
                                t.stringLiteral(path.node.loc.start.line.toString()),
                                t.stringLiteral(path.node.loc.start.column.toString()),
                            ]
                        )
                    )
                );
                path.get('body').pushContainer('body',
                    t.expressionStatement(
                        t.callExpression(
                            t.memberExpression(
                                t.identifier('console'),
                                t.identifier('log')
                            ), [
                                t.stringLiteral("JSTracer LEAVE:"),
                                t.stringLiteral(state.file.opts.filename),
                                t.stringLiteral(path.node.loc.start.line.toString()),
                                t.stringLiteral(path.node.loc.start.column.toString()),
                            ]
                        )
                    )
                );
            },
            ReturnStatement(path, state) {
                if (state.file.opts.filename.endsWith('node_modules/react-native/Libraries/polyfills/console.js')) return;
                ContainingFunction = path.getFunctionParent();
                if (typeof(ContainingFunction.node.loc) === 'undefined') return;
                path.insertBefore(
                    t.expressionStatement(
                        t.callExpression(
                            t.memberExpression(
                                t.identifier('console'),
                                t.identifier('log')
                            ), [
                                t.stringLiteral("JSTracer LEAVE:"),
                                t.stringLiteral(state.file.opts.filename),
                                t.stringLiteral(ContainingFunction.node.loc.start.line.toString()),
                                t.stringLiteral(ContainingFunction.node.loc.start.column.toString()),
                            ]
                        )
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    };
};
```